# Ebay API FixedPriceTransaction - ReturnedTransactionCountActual returns 0?

Tags: c#, ebay-api

When an item is bought with Buy It Now and immediate payment, my code is being triggered correctly (the code sends me an email to test it).

What I want is the ebay item id of the item sold which I believe is here (found this sample in the documentation):

```
<GetItemTransactionsResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2015-07-02T00:09:03.273Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>967</Version>
  <Build>E967_CORE_BUNDLED_11481347_R1</Build>
  <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfPages>1</TotalNumberOfPages>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>1</TotalNumberOfEntries>
  </PaginationResult>
  <HasMoreTransactions>false</HasMoreTransactions>
  <TransactionsPerPage>100</TransactionsPerPage>
  <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
  <ReturnedTransactionCountActual>1</ReturnedTransactionCountActual>
  <Item>
    <AutoPay>false</AutoPay>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    **<ItemID>110048746230</ItemID>**
```

I'm using the eBay API:

```
public void EbayCall(GetItemTransactionsResponseType response)
```

Is that the correct object to expect? I can't see why response.ReturnedTransactionCountActual is 0. Also response.Item.ItemID is null.

response.Ack returns Success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting an xml response.  The ID is shown as 110048746230.  The xml can easily be parsed in c#.  I sued XML Linq below with Load(string FILENAME) method but you can use a string with Parse(string XML) method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string itemID = (string)doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ItemID").FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, that XML is just a sample. I would rather use the API than parse the XML myself.

Comment: Does the API actually  have a method that parses XML?